# How to use having with or condition in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two similler  queries with same table name  which are working fine individually. But I want to merge them with condition **((city_id = 1 and country_id = 1) or distance < "20")**

**First query**

```
select id , lat , long , city_id , country_id 
from element_table
where city_id = 1 and country_id = 1 and id < 20
```

**Second query**
    Here I am using search with lat lon

```
 select id , lat , long , city_id , country_id ,
 my_distance_calculationformula_with_lat_long as distance  
 from element_table where id < 20 having distance = "20"
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316600/using-or-between-having-and-where-clause-in-mysql

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: You can also use UNION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use where and having

```
select id , lat , long , city_id , country_id ,
my_distance_calculationformula_with_lat_long as distance  
from element_table
where city_id = 1 and country_id = 1 and id < 20 
having distance = 20
```

in you case  (your comment)
Then you should not use an alias and perform only the where

```
select id , lat , long , city_id , country_id ,
my_distance_calculationformula_with_lat_long as distance  
from element_table
where city_id = 1 and country_id = 1 and id < 20 
or   my_distance_calculationformula_with_lat_long < 20
```

*(and if your my_distance_calculationformula_with_lat_long is a long sql code .  you should repeat the code for not using alias ..column alias in not allowed in where)*

Comment: i want to make condition like this ((city_id = 1 and country_id = 1) or distance < "20")