# Rails & ActiveRecord: Difficult SQL Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my Rails app I allow users to "vote" on events. Some events are one specific date only and some events are ongoing.

I am trying to build a query that renders all the events that either A) a user has *not* voted on *OR* B) the ongoing events a user has voted on *over* 1 month ago.

Event has a "ongoing" boolean column. Event has_many votes. And User has_many votes.

Here's my query to get all the events a user has *not* voted on. It works.

```
scope :unvoted, ->(user_id) {
    joins(
         "LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.event_id = events.id AND " +
         "votes.user_id = #{user_id}"
         ).where("votes.id IS NULL")
    }
```

I am trying to add the *or* part of the query. I need to include "ongoing" events that the user has voted on over a month ago. Here's what I tried:

```
scope :unvoted, ->(user_id) {
    joins(
          "LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.event_id = events.id AND " +
          "votes.user_id = #{user_id}"
         )
         .where(
                 "votes.id IS NULL OR events.ongoing = ? AND MAX(votes.created_at) < ?", true, 1.month.ago
          )
  }
```

But this is giving me the error:

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

So I tried this:

```
scope :unvoted, ->(user_id) {
    joins(
          "LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.event_id = events.id AND " +
          "votes.user_id = #{user_id}"
                            ).
   having('votes.id IS NULL OR events.ongoing = ? AND MAX("votes"."created_at") < ?', true, 1.month.ago).
   group("events.id")
  }
```

But this is giving me the error:

> ERROR: column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

What's the proper query that I'm looking for?

Comment: For complex SQL questions make sure to tag them with the RDBMS and create a good example of the tables and expected result. There are far more followers for the postgres and mysql tags than ruby-on-rails for example and you tend to get better answers.

Comment: What is your purpose for using MAX? Just get a latest one from matched records, or order records from new to old?

Comment: @YTorii I need to get the latest one from matched records to see if it was created over a month ago

Comment: You might like to express that second one as "the ongoing events for which there is no vote for the user within the last month". In SQL terms, a simple NOT EXISTS correlated subquery, or maybe an outer join if you wanted to go that route.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** 
Seems there is no way of writing OR with HAVING. You can use a subquery([Using 'OR' between HAVING and WHERE clause in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316600/using-or-between-having-and-where-clause-in-mysql)) or UNION to solve this.

Or to keep things simple you can break this into two queries.

only ActiveRecord solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15413611/5213979

Comment: Hmmm.. I'm not sure if this will work because it will return all events with a vote older than 1 month ago. But I only want to return events where the most recent vote was over 1 month ago

Comment: @JacksonCunningham Ok, realized that.

Comment: Can you provide an example of doing this with two queries? I like this approach but not sure how to do it with "OR"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
scope :unvoted, ->(user_id) {
    joins(
      "LEFT OUTER JOIN votes ON votes.event_id = events.id AND " +
      "votes.user_id = #{user_id}"
    ).where(
      "votes.id IS NULL OR events.ongoing = ?", true                      
    ).select('events.*, MAX(votes.created_at) as created_at')
    ).group('events.id')
}
```

and then in your method, you can do

`Event.unvoted.select{|e| e.created_at < 1.month.ago}`